# Indefinite Integration problem

Tags: calculus, integration

$$ \int \limits^{\frac{\pi }{2} }_{\frac{-\pi }{2}}\frac{x^2 \cos(x) }{e^x+1} \, dx $$ 
My question is how can get this integration in the closed form? thanks.  Any hint will help.

Answer (score 4):

Since $\frac{1}{e^x+1}+\frac{1}{e^{-x}+1}=1$,

$$ I = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{x^2\cos x}{e^x} = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}x^2\cos(x)\,dx = \left.2x\cos x+(x^2-2)\sin x\,\right|_{0}^{\pi/2}\\ = \color{red}{\frac{\pi^2-8}{4}}.$$

Comment: Thanks sir.  But  question how we remove  $1$ in the denominator in the integration ?

Comment: Letting $u=-x$, you can show that $\displaystyle I=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{x^2\cos x}{e^x+1}\,dx=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{x^2\cos x}{e^{-x}+1}\,dx$, hence $\displaystyle 2I=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} x^2\cos x\,dx$. Since $x^2\cos x$ is even, you have $\displaystyle I=\int_0^{\pi/2}x^2\cos x\,dx$. The result follows via integration by parts.

Comment: @user256952: sorry for the delay, I was kind of busy; anyway user170231 is perfectly right, I just exploited $$\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{a}\left(f(x)+f(-x)\right)\,dx$$ and integration by parts.

Comment: Cool problem, because this technique works if you maintain the same denominator, but replace the numerator with any even function.